# Android NDK tutorials?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Are there any decent Android NDK examples and tutorials out there? Where can I find them? If there are any geared more specifically towards game engine development (as I am looking to convert mine over to android) that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/game-development-for-android-quick.html) a while about android game programming on the official blog. Also Quake was ported to Android using a mix of Java and Native code and has been [open sourced](http://grammerjack.blogspot.com/2009/10/gles-quake-port-of-quake-to-android.html). Not sure how good it is from a tutorial standpoint but looking at real code always helps me more than following a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

check out : http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/tag/android-ndk-tutorial/

Comment: There is nothing there, or nothing anymore.

Comment: There is this article https://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/blog/android/using-android-ndk-to-call-native-code-from-android-application/
For now this should be a good resource https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/

Answer (score -2):

Here is one complete documentation.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html

Comment: JNI is related to but clearly [different](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Using) to NDK. Consider editing or deleting your post. And btw, link is broken.